# if else not working in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to the batch script. I added the if else in the batch script. 1st if else works once but not all the time, and the 2nd is not working all the time cant find the issue it, can some one help me in this
I'm getting the Counter value by using the for loop.

> ```
> if %Counter% equ %SuccessCounter% (  
>     echo List.csv,%Counter%,%SuccessCounter%,%date% %time%,True >> %statusfile%  
> ) else (
>     set partUpload_flag=1    
>     echo List.csv,%Counter%,%SuccessCounter%,%date% %time%,False >>%statusfile%
> )
>
>
>
> if %ErrorCounter% gtr 1 (    
>     set success_flag=0
>     set Attachment= %Attachment% -attach error.csv
>     echo ERROR:Error found in Account records:%ErrorCounter% lines >> %logpath%
>     ::Having error in account file
> )
> ```

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. %errorCounter% is not set anywhere. Could you post a complete example which can reproduce the issue? However, remove all the stuff that is not needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: What `for` loop? Is this code within a `for` loop? "Works" is a relative term. Please say what exactly happens and what you expect to happen. Are you aware that batch does not "clear" variables from one run to the next unless you use a `setlocal` to undo any changes made after the `setlocal` is executed? Is the variability run-to-run? Are you aware that within a `for` loop, `%var%` means `the value of VAR when the loop started`?

Answer (score 0):

The `::` in this line are a problem in a loop in that position.  Use `REM` instead.

```
::Having error in account file
```

Comment: hi even after removing the line ::Having error in account  not running if %Counter% equ %SuccessCounter% (  
    echo List.csv,%Counter%,%SuccessCounter%,%date% %time%,True >> %statusfile%  
) else (
    set partUpload_flag=1    
    echo List.csv,%Counter%,%SuccessCounter%,%date% %time%,False >>%statusfile%
)

Comment: Make sure your variables actually have a value. Another point is that `%date%` and `%time%` will not be updated within a loop unless delayed expansion is used.